# Excel formula: counting array elements with a criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have an array, which is the result of the multiplication of two COUNTIF functions.

The result is {0,2,7,4,0}. I want to count the number of non-zero elements. I tried the following:

=COUNTIF(COUNTIF*COUNTIF,">0") <- here the two inner COUNTIFs are short for the complete formula

It did not work. I then tried the following, which did not work either.

=COUNTIF({0,2,7,4,0},">0")

I resorted to using the following array formula and it worked.

{=SUM(IF(COUNTIF*COUNTIF>0,1,0))}

Two questions:

1. does COUNTIF only accept cell reference but not constant array?
2. any solution other than array formula?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `=sumproduct(--((COUNTIF*COUNTIF)>0))` work? sumproduct provides one level of the cyclic calculation of an array formula.

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first argument of COUNTIF must be a range, nothing else will do.
2. You can just enter this as an ordinary formula:

   =SUM(--({0,2,7,4,0}>0))
3. However when the array comes from a calculation, you need to coerce it to process all the elements either

   =SUM(INDEX(--(A1:A5>0),0))

or like @Jeeped with Sumproduct

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5>0))
```

Comment: Great! I'm sorry I can't provide any real insight into the difference between 2 & 3 above, I'm guessing if the expression passed to SUM is already an array it will evaluate it as such.